# Travis fails to stop Docker containers

Tags: docker, travis-ci

I'm using Travis to build my project: https://github.com/Krijger/docker-gradle

The build uses Docker and Docker Compose. During the build, I try to stop a running container, which results in a `permission denied`.

https://travis-ci.org/Krijger/docker-gradle/builds/82739195

```
ERROR: for dockerplugin_service_1  Cannot stop container d23b7e9fc2a7bec16bdef883177d7df5582e8de2736b8623e878be6a4943c8b0: 
[8] System error: permission denied
```

I am not alone in this issue. I'm seeing this in other Travis builds as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and had no satisfactory solution. I know this won't make an acceptable answer but I figured I could save you some time by sharing a few links.

- [Related issue](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/4661) on the TravisCI issue tracker
- the [`kill -9`](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15101#issuecomment-128712142) trick
- [similar issue](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/pull/743) on the docker-py project

It seems [some succeeded](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/4661#issuecomment-142306744) with the use of the `--privileged` flag

---

**Edit:** [it was reported](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/4661#issuecomment-147089876) that the following lines added to the *.travis.yml* config files does the trick:

```
install:
  # place apparmor docker profile in complain mode
  # to workaround https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/4661
  - sudo apt-get -y update
  - sudo apt-get -y install apparmor-utils
  - sudo aa-complain /etc/apparmor.d/docker
```

---

For me, I just gave up TravisCI and moved to [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/docs/docker) which natively offers Docker 1.5 and also makes it possible to have Docker 1.7.1 if you start your yml file with:

```yaml
machine:
  pre:
    # install docker 1.7.1
    - sudo curl -L -o /usr/bin/docker 'https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/circle-downloads/docker-1.7.1-circleci'; sudo chmod 0755 /    usr/bin/docker; true
  services:
    - docker
```

Comment: The same issue now states:
Hmm, looks like the workaround I proposed is not necessary anymore. It seems to work now OOTB. I haven't found any reference yet why this is the case. Probably apparmor has been removed as directory /etc/apparmor.d does not exist anymore.